# Vuetify bottom navigation got glitches on ios browser

Tags: css, vue.js

[image: The icons and text on navigation become like in the red circle]

Im using vuetify bottom navigation and google material icons for this navbar. But when open in ios browser, (tried chrome and safari) the navigation menu become like in the image above. Especially after scrolling up and down. Sometimes not appear but mostly it appear. It is fine on android browser.

What is the possible problem here? Is it in the css i need to use something like oberflow touch or something in html?

```
<v-bottom-nav fixed color="accent" :value="true" :active.sync="e1">
  <v-btn to="/" flat color="white" value="home">
    <span>Beranda</span>
    <v-icon>home</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn to="/orders" flat color="white" value="orders">
    <span>Pesanan</span>
    <v-icon>history</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn to="/favorites" flat color="white" value="favorites">
    <span>Favorit</span>
    <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
  <v-btn to="/profile" flat color="white" value="profile">
    <span>Profil</span>
    <v-icon>person</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</v-bottom-nav>
```

Thanks,